# django view does not return httpresponse object though am returning one

Tags: django

hey guys i am developing a project management website using django, am getting this error `The view equipo.frontends.views.hoddashboard didn't return an HttpResponse object` when i authenticate a user the login to the dashboard.

my views.py is as follows:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.template import Context
    from django.forms import *
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
    from django.contrib import auth 
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

    def hoddashboard(request):
         if request.method=='POST':
             username=request.POST.get('Username')
             password=request.POST.get('Password')
             user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
             if user is not None:
                 auth.login(request, user)
                 team="team.png"
                 t={'team1':team}
                 return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/aditya/Desktop/equipo/equipo/frontend      /templates/hodnewdash.html')
```

and my html page is as follows:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>hod-login</title>
            <style type="text/css">.hod2{position:absolute;left:160;top:150;}
                .hod1{position:absolute;left:870;top:180;}
                .hod2{position:absolute;left:160;top:150;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
             <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
      <img src='{{MEDIA_URL}}hod.png' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
    </div>
            <img height="300" width="450" class="hod2" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}hod1.jpeg" />
             {%block content %}
            <form action="hodnewdash.html" class="hod1" method="POST" name="hodlogin">{% csrf_token %}
                <label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="uname" size="20"> </input><br />
                <br />



                <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" />
                <br /><br />
                <input  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="hodnewdash.html" />
            </form>
        {% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything if your URL is requested directly (with `GET`), and you have some other unhandled conditions:

```
 def hoddashboard(request):
         if request.method=='POST':
            # do stuff
            if user is not None:
               # do stuff
               return redirect('/some/url')
            else:
               return redirect('/some/url2/')
         else:
            return redirect('/somewhere/else/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review the response from Burhan, the skeleton of the method hoddashboard is better.

Any way, you are not using in the right way the HttpResponseRedirect, you should pass as parameter the URL where you want to redirect to the user. For example, if you want the user goes to http://yoursite.com/dashboard/ you must use:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
```

That response will runs the dashboard method in your code and returns its response.

You can red the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect